# How can I force Django to create test database with a certain collation?

Tags: django

I have a Postgres install that is set to use LATIN1 as the default encoding. However, my production database requires that I use UTF8 (it's hosted on Heroku, so I don't have any choice in this).

I have created my local dev database to have this set correctly:

```
sudo createdb -Upostgres $PROJECT_NAME --template=template0 \
    --encoding=UTF8 --lc-collate=en_US.UTF-8 --lc-ctype=en_US.UTF-8
```

however, I now can't run the django tests, as the test database just uses the default Postgres cluster settings (LATIN1), which causes the tests to fail (I have invalid chars in some of the templates - `...character 0xe28099 of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "LATIN1"`)

The 'nuclear' option is to reinstall Postgres with the correct (en_US.UTF8) settings, however since I am running this in a VM, each time I spin up the VM I don't really want to have to do this. If there was a way of massaging Django to create the database correctly in the first place that would be preferable.

**[UPDATE 1: TEST_ENCODING]**

Following up on @sneawo's suggestion, I have set the TEST_ENCODING attribute of the database, and now get the following error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: encoding UTF8 does not match locale en_US
DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding LATIN1.
```

**[UPDATE 2: nuclear option]**

I referred to this above, and it's not for everyone, but since I am running this on a VM it's actually pretty easy for me to recreate the postgres cluster with the correct collation in my Vagrant provision script (shell script):

```
sudo service postgresql stop
sudo pg_dropcluster 9.1 --stop main
sudo pg_createcluster --start -e UTF-8 9.1 main
sudo cp -f $CONF_DIR/pg_hba.conf /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
sudo cp -f $CONF_DIR/postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
sudo service postgresql restart
```

I have default 'allow everything' versions of `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` that I copy over from the host machine to overwrite the defaults that are created when creating the cluster. It's a bit of sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut solution, but it does work, and it's quick.

Comment: Did you set [TEST_CHARSET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#test-charset) setting?

Comment: Great suggestion - I didn't even know about that. I have now set it, but am getting a locale / encoding mismatch issue.

Comment: +1 for Vagrant. Exactly the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the bottom settings.py

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Add this code in local_settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'latin1',
                    'use_unicode': True, },
    }, 
}
```

Add local_settings.py into git ignore.

Comment: That would work with MySQL, but Postgres doesn't support the 'charset' option.